# How to send a raw IPL to intermec pm4i printer using C# via USB

Tags: c#, printers, intermec, ipl

Good Morning,
I need to send an IPL command to usb printer, but I do not even know how to get started.
Can anybody help me?

the ipl code is:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5fjx01OqT4KcUh0LVdkZEtfWkE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows (not Linux Mono), I think the best way is to use the Intermec driver software and create a local USB printer.  Once you have a printer created in the O.S., you can just send it raw data.  Here's the microsoft link that shows you how to do that ...

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322091/how-to-send-raw-data-to-a-printer-by-using-visual-c-.net#top